# FFMPEG cut video and concat put it in reverse

Tags: ffmpeg

I received a script that cuts video into sub-clips with a specific durationand  then `concat`s them again but for some reason the script `concat`s the files in reverse order:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBCLIPS=4 
OUTPUTLENGTH=10

cliplength=$(echo "$OUTPUTLENGTH/$SUBCLIPS"| bc -l)

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    videofile="$1"
else
    echo "file not found: $1"
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$2" ]; then
    OUTPUTFILE="$2"
else
    echo "No name given"
    exit 1
fi

ffmpeg_preamble="ffmpeg -hide_banner -i '$videofile' -s 320x240 -filter_complex \""

duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of         default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$videofile")

cutfilters=""
concatfilter=""

for cutno in $( seq 1 $SUBCLIPS ); do
  cut=$(echo "(1 / ($SUBCLIPS+1)) * $cutno" | bc -l)
  cutchar= $cutno+96
  reverse=  $(printf "%sreverse")
  cutletter=$(printf "\x$(printf %x $cutchar)")
  cutpos=$(echo "$duration * $cut" |bc)
  cutfilters=$(printf "%s[0:v]trim=start=%f:duration=%f,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[%sv];" "$cutfilters" "$cutpos" "$cliplength" "$cutletter")
  cutfilters=$(printf "%s[0:a]atrim=start=%f:duration=%f,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[%sa];" "$cutfilters" "$cutpos" "$cliplength" "$cutletter")
  concatfilter=$(printf "%s[%sv][%sa]" "$concatfilter" "$cutletter" "$cutletter")
done

# concat the cuts together

concatfilter=$(printf "%sconcat=n=%s:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" "$concatfilter"     "$SUBCLIPS")

ffmpeg_webmopts=" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "
ffmpeg_postscript="\" -map [outv] -map [outa] $ffmpeg_webmopts '$OUTPUTFILE'"

# Chance to cancel before we start

printf "***(hit ctrl+c to cancel)***\n\nExecuting: %s%s%s%s\n"     "$ffmpeg_preamble" "$cutfilters" "$concatfilter" "$ffmpeg_postscript"
sleep 3
eval $(echo "$ffmpeg_preamble $cutfilters $concatfilter $ffmpeg_postscript")
```

*How do I implement the above without reversal?*

Comment: There are multiple errors in the script that I can see that are unrecoverable.  Can you copy-paste the script *as is* (don't try to make it pretty) and ping me afterwards

Comment: I took it from here and modified for my needs.
https://superuser.com/questions/1298270/ffmpeg-mp4-to-webm-make-a-10-second-compilation-based-on-length

Comment: Use https://shellcheck.net when adapting scripts to check for syntax errors.  Do that first and then copy-paste what you currently have, then ping me @Fabby again.